# RichEditCtrl and its text content

Tags: c++, c, mfc, cricheditctrl

I copy all formatted rich edit text into clipboard as

```
m_edit.setsel(0,-1);
m_edit.copy();
```

But when I call `GetClipboardData`,
I obtain text without format.
Someone could explain to me something about this ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mistaken. The copy method sends a WM_COPY message to the control. This will place formatted text as well as plain text on the clipboard. Look through all the formats on the clipboard and you will find RTF is present.